# problem to create directory in codeigniter 3 on macbookpro

Tags: php, macos, codeigniter, unix, codeigniter-3

I'm trying to create a directory in a controller in CI
this is the code

```
$path="/cubo/application/aziende/";
mkdir($path, 0775, true);
```

I receive this message:
[image]

I'm trying to put the 777 to htdocs folder but it does not work anyway

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried to check the process owner?

```
$processUser = posix_getpwuid(posix_geteuid());
echo($processUser['name']);
```

and if the group shown as `nobody` it means it's restricted.

Make sure all files are owned by the Apache group and user. In Ubuntu it is the `www-data` group and user

`chown -R www-data:www-data /path/to/webserver/www`

Next enabled all members of the www-data group to read and write files

`chmod -R g+rw /path/to/webserver/www`

Comment: Edited. I think it is impossible that you don`t have any user privilege there. Have an [idea here.](https://www.linuxquestions.org/questions/linux-security-4/which-user-should-own-var-www-873287/page2.html#post4316009)

Comment: i have macbook not ubuntu

Answer (score 0):

run this command in your terminal for your project. uploads is folder name

```
sudo chmod -R 0777 uploads
```

Answer (score 0):

In your code, you are giving permission `0775`

Try to use `0777` permission to create the folder

```
$dir = "/cubo/application/aziende/";
if (!is_dir($dir)) {
     mkdir($dir, 0777, TRUE);
}
```